# Какой смысл от sass и scss?

Tags: scss, sass

Читаю статью и там пишут о том, что он ускоряет написание css, так же имеются переменные. Эмм... И что? У css тоже есть переменные (:root). Расскажите пожалуйста, какой от них смысл, так же, пожалуйста, приложите примеры)

Comment: Там не только есть переменные, но и циклы, условия, функции можно сказать. Если говорить только о переменных, то действительно преимущество небольшое

Comment: Ну просто смотрю видосы где верстают, там используют только подключение, переменные и в принципе все. Но это можно сделать на css и даже быстрее

Comment: Возможно, стоит ещё обратить внимание, что в препроцессорах все вычисления происходят в compile time